# Change action bar up indicator to default back arrow button after changing it with custom drawable

Tags: android, kotlin

So, whenever I create an Activity, I set custom up indicator icon like this:

```
private fun setupActionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.custom_drawable)
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

My question is - how can I change `setHomeAsUpIndicator` as default back arrow from fragment?

Comment: call this from your fragment ((YourActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setupActionBar();  this time  commen t  setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.custom_drawable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside onAttach(context:Context) function in fragment you can access the actionBar

```
override fun onAttach(context : Context) {
        if (context is YourParentActivity) {
            val activity = context as YourParentActivity
            activity.supportActionBar?.apply{
                setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
                setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
                setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_deafault_back_arrow)
                setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

               //Here Customize your  action bar as much as you want
            }
        }
}
```

Enjoy Coding: Please let me know if you have any other problem with it

Comment: "R.drawable.your_deafault_back_arrow" - for this I need a custom drawable. That's not what I am looking for. I want to set default one provided by Android itself.

Comment: The appcompat arrow is this: `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` At least in the last support library, the name changed over the years.